RESTEasy + Guice servlet deploy failure with error: "this.modules" is null
I'm using RESTEasy + Guice to handle my servlet plumbing when deployed to Tomcat.  It generally works really well, but I ran into a problem after some recent work, resulting in errors and failed initialization of my servlet.
The Tomcat logs are not especially helpful, so I'd appreciate it if someone had any suggestions for what the real source of the problem is.  Logs are below...
$ cat catalina.2024-10-15.log
15-Oct-2024 18:18:35.158 INFO [31] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableSortedSet]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableSortedSet]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1200)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1047)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1014)
                at com.google.common.collect.CollectCollectors.<clinit>(CollectCollectors.java:63)
                at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList(ImmutableList.java:77)
                at com.google.inject.internal.MissingImplementationErrorHints.getSuggestions(MissingImplementationErrorHints.java:55)
                at com.google.inject.internal.MissingImplementationError.lambda$new$0(MissingImplementationError.java:27)
                at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:200)
                at com.google.inject.internal.MissingImplementationError.formatDetail(MissingImplementationError.java:50)
                at com.google.inject.spi.ErrorDetail.format(ErrorDetail.java:64)
                at com.google.inject.internal.Messages.formatMessages(Messages.java:90)
                at com.google.inject.CreationException.getMessage(CreationException.java:50)
                at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.getLocalizedMessage(Throwable.java:398)
                at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.toString(Throwable.java:497)
                at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4465)
                at java.base/java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:1021)
                at org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter$IndentingPrintWriter.println(OneLineFormatter.java:275)
                at java.base/java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:801)
                at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.lockedPrintStackTrace(Throwable.java:684)
                at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:673)
                at java.base/java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:749)
                at org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter.format(OneLineFormatter.java:159)
                at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:234)
                at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.publishInternal(AsyncFileHandler.java:138)
                at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler$1.run(AsyncFileHandler.java:131)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)


$ cat localhost_access_log.2024-10-15.txt
15-Oct-2024 18:18:35.154 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [dev.resteasy.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener]
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "this.modules" is null
                at dev.resteasy.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.triggerAnnotatedMethods(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:131)
                at dev.resteasy.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.contextDestroyed(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4012)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:4616)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:231)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:168)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:566)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:653)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:933)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:735)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:387)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1593)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:267)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:385)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:332)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:771)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1170)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1160)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:716)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:866)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:755)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:470)



Aha-- the problem was that I added a new class in my Guice module and registered it with just a regular bind( ) call.  The class actually relies on an @Assisted factory constructor, so I needed to register it with Guice via something like this:
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(APNSThreadWorker.Factory.class));
Once I did that, the .war deployed correctly.  Whew.
